# bootstrap 4 equivalent for form-control-feedback

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

`form-control-feedback` does not seem to be part of bootstrap 4. What's the best way to achieve the below result (icon inside the textbox) using bootstrap 4?

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group has-warning has-feedback">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    <span class="form-control-feedback"><i class="fa fa-rotate-right"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of "Bootstrap 4 form input with icon for validation". This question is asking about help text and not using icons in valid or invalid messages. The correct answer is to use two classes with Bootstrap 4.3: `form-text text-muted`. This is documented under the "Help Text" section of the 4.3 docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#help-text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just jack the css class and apply it (notice the v4 cdn) the same but minus the fixed sizing conventions like;

```css
.form-control-feedback {
    position: absolute;
    top: .5rem;
    right: 1.5rem;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;   
    text-align: center;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group has-warning has-feedback">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    <span class="form-control-feedback"><i class="fa fa-rotate-right"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

However, note that if you go in and play with the sass settings for your input sizing etc, the `top` and `right` values will need tweaked accordingly along with possibly a font-size added.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, I was wondering if there is a built in bootstrap solution... I would use your answer if no built in class is found.

Comment: @Hooman that is the original class from bootstrap 3, there is none equivalent in bootstrap4 since most folks now opt to place the icon in the Placeholder these days via like `input {font-family: 'FontAwesome'}` then `placeholder="\iconUnicode\"` that I know anyway.